# How can I debug queries sent via mysql2?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysqljs

From the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) readme we read :

> MySQL2 is mostly API compatible with
> [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

Which package has an option defined as :

> - **debug**: Prints protocol details to stdout. Can be true/false or an array of packet type names that should be printed. (Default: false)

This option even has an example :

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({debug: ['ComQueryPacket', 'RowDataPacket']});
```

However, setting this option with either `true`, `"ComQueryPacket"` and/or `"RowDataPacket"` vomits a ton load of irrelevant data; all I care is to have the SQL query and variables being sent. How can this be done with this package?

Answer (score 2):

`debug` option only supports true/false values in mysql2. Easiest way to log all queries would be to monkey patch Connection.prototype.addCommand, example pseudocode:

```
let addCommand = Connection.prototype.addCommand
function loggingAddCommand(cmd) {
  if (cmd.constructor === Commands.Query) {
    console.log(`Adding query command, sql: ${cmd.sql}`);
  }
  this.addCommand(cmd);
}

connection.addCommand = loggingAddCommand;
```

I'll try to think about better api to make this easier. Maybe having "command" event on a connection? If we add this, above example would become `conn.on('command_added', cmd => { /* ... */ })`

Comment: Hey! Thank you for answering! If you're open to suggestion (I could even open an issue ticket on Github?), then perhaps `conn.on("afterExecute", ({ sql, params, result, error }) => { ... })` would allow for debugging. An event `beforeExecute` could also be emitted with only the `sql` and `params` options.